# Invalid Dynamic Link on accessing https://app.page.link (no query params)

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

Here is my **Firebase Dynamic Links** page:
[image]

On running this command: `npx uri-scheme open "https://app.page.link" --android` - notice there is no query params in the link, a web page is opened on **Android** as expected, but with the following content:
[image]

It is working find when I add **/c8Ci** or **/bbb** at the end, but it throws me the error above when the link is clear (without any query params)

To be short:

**Android**:

```
https://app.page.link/bbb - success (app launched)
https://app.page.link/c8Ci - success (app launched)
https://app.page.link - fail
```

**iOS**

```
https://app.page.link/bbb - success (app launched)
https://app.page.link/c8Ci - success (app launched)
https://app.page.link - success (app launched)
```

Can you please help me to figure out what's wrong with my Dynamic Linking.

**Thank you mates in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time and the issue was the TEAM ID.
If your project is old your TEAM ID and App ID Prefix are not the same, keep/change the team id in https://console.firebase.google.com with App ID Prefix(https://developer.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is an expected behavior when you try to open the "https://app.page.link" directly, as its purpose is solely for Dynamic Links domain only. Note that Firebase provides a default 'page.link' subdomain for your Dynamic Links for free, this is because you can't use the same domain for both Dynamic Links and regular hosting. The domain is not configured to behave as a regular Hosting domain.

This is why configuring a short link URL allows you to redirect your users to you app. And visiting the domain directly returns an invalid page.

As for iOS, I can only assume it was cached that’s why it worked.

I guess it is best reaching out directly to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) regarding this as there could be any other underlying reasons that could cause this.